# Password visible when Typing then ***

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I would like to make my password field visible when typing and when finished (change to another field) convert it to ***.
As my app has only one password field (no confirmation) its easy the user mistype.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you just use a secure textField that automatically hides the text as the user types?

Comment: This sounds like a fine idea. I suggest you **write some code.**

Comment: @MattBall who are you talking to?

Comment: @Joel I was addressing the OP.

Comment: @Jeremy I would assume this is for a signup form, not a login form.

Comment: @Joel Instagram app does this, when you are typing the password is visible, then coded. Because as it has only one field for password, is easy to user mistype.

Comment: Use a standard password text field.  It will allow you to see one character in plain text at a time as you type.  If you MUST show the whole password, when it loses first responder, hide the box or replace the contents of the box with a bunch of asterisks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
UITextField *txtPassword = [[UITextField alloc] init];
txtPassword.secureTextEntry =YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

- set `pwdTextField.delegate = self`
- implement `textfieldDidEndEditing` delegate
- Do nothing special while user input text
- Now in `textfieldDidEndEditing` store your current password in a variable (for future use)
- Replace `pwdTextField.text = noOfStarsEqualToLenghtOfString`

That's it. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest to use the secure textfield. Otherwise try this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == txtPassword)
    {
         //Check total no of characters in that textfield & replace all with *.
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And on confirm button clicked(register/login), check the password with the password which you added before replacing with *. Consider * just for displaying purpose.